# Python and m2crypto load certificate and private key from string

Tags: python, m2crypto

Could you help me with m2crypto?

The code below is to return the 'HTTP / 1.1 403 Forbidden' server.
The certificate and the private key are not loaded in the code:

```
from M2Crypto import Rand, SSL, httpslib, threading , BIO , X509 , RSA
ctx = SSL.Context('sslv23')
store = ctx.get_cert_store()
bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
bio.write( str( open( 'certi.pem', 'r' ).read() ) )
store.add_x509( X509.load_cert_bio(bio) )

# or
# store.add_x509( X509.load_cert_string( str(open( 'certi.pem', 'r' ).read()) ) )

ctx.set_verify( SSL.verify_none, depth=1 )    
ctx.set_info_callback()
h = httpslib.HTTPSConnection( ‘Server’, 443, ssl_context=ctx )
h.set_debuglevel(1)
h.request( 'mysoap' )
```

and when I do so, it works:

```
from M2Crypto import Rand, SSL, httpslib, threading , BIO , X509 , RSA
ctx = SSL.Context('sslv23')
ctx.load_cert_chain( str( 'certi.pem' ) ) 
ctx.set_verify( SSL.verify_none, depth=1 )    
ctx.set_info_callback()
h = httpslib.HTTPSConnection( ‘Server’, 443, ssl_context=ctx )
h.set_debuglevel(1)
h.request( 'mysoap' )
```

Thank's